# bash- find average of numbers in line

Tags: arrays, bash, expr

I am trying to read a file line by line and find the average of the numbers in each line.  I am getting the error: `expr: non-numeric argument`

I have narrowed the problem down to sum=`expr $sum + $i`, but I'm not sure why the code doesn't work.

```
while read -a rows
do
    for i in "${rows[@]}"
    do
        sum=`expr $sum + $i`
        total=`expr $total + 1`
    done
    average=`expr $sum / $total`
done < $fileName
```

The file looks like this (the numbers are separated by tabs):

```
1       1       1       1       1
9       3       4       5       5
6       7       8       9       7
3       6       8       9       1
3       4       2       1       4
6       4       4       7       7
```

Comment: I think your code is ok, maybe your file contains non-numeric (integer) values.

Comment: No the file is all numbers.  Its a grid of all numbers.  Is it possible it is looking at the spaces in between the numbers trying to compute those?

Comment: @NateDawg87 Can you include in the question a sample line (or two) from the file that causes your code errors?

Comment: @John1024 I added what the file looks like

Comment: @NateDawg87 Is `$filename` supposed to be the input file or the output file?

Comment: @John1024 `$fileName` is the input file.  I copied the code wrong, I actually have `done < $fileName` in my code.  Just edited it.  Still same problem though.

Comment: You really need to initialize sum and total at the beginning of each line. Otherwise, they keep adding to the values from the previous line.

Comment: While you can't actually do floating point math in bash, you can fake it for a simple task like this. Check out the lower section of my answer, below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some minor corrections, your code runs well:

```
while read -a rows
do
    total=0
    sum=0
    for i in "${rows[@]}"
    do
        sum=`expr $sum + $i`
        total=`expr $total + 1`
    done
    average=`expr $sum / $total`
    echo $average
done <filename
```

With the sample input file, the output produced is:

```
1
5
7
5
2
5
```

Note that the answers are what they are because `expr` only does integer arithmetic.

#### Using sed to preprocess for expr

The above code could be rewritten as:

```
$ while read row; do expr '(' $(sed 's/  */ + /g' <<<"$row") ')' / $(wc -w<<<$row); done < filename
1
5
7
5
2
5
```

#### Using bash's builtin arithmetic capability

`expr` is archaic.  In modern bash:

```
while read -a rows
do
    total=0
    sum=0
    for i in "${rows[@]}"
    do
        ((sum += $i))
        ((total++))
    done
    echo $((sum/total))
done <filename
```

#### Using awk for floating point math

Because awk does floating point math, it can provide more accurate results:

```
$ awk '{s=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)s+=$i; print s/NF;}' filename
1
5.2
7.4
5.4
2.8
5.6
```

Comment: In your bash solution, wouldn't `$total` be the same as `${#rows[@]}`?

Answer (score 1):

Some variations on the same trick of using the IFS variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    set -- $line
    echo $(( ( $(IFS=+; echo "$*") ) / $# ))
done < rows

echo

while read -a line; do
    echo $(( ( $(IFS=+; echo "${line[*]}") ) / ${#line[*]} ))
done < rows

echo

saved_ifs="$IFS"
while read -a line; do
    IFS=+
    echo $(( ( ${line[*]} ) / ${#line[*]} ))
    IFS="$saved_ifs"
done < rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out that `expr` is integer-only, and recommended writing your script in awk instead of shell.

Your system may have a number of tools on it that support arbitrary-precision math, or floats.  Two common calculators in shell are `bc` which follows standard "order of operations", and `dc` which uses "reverse polish notation".

Either one of these can easily be fed your data such that per-line averages can be produced.  For example, using bc:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line; do
  set - ${line}
  c=$#
  string=""
  for n in $*; do
    string+="${string:++}$1"
    shift
  done
  average=$(printf 'scale=4\n(%s) / %d\n' $string $c | bc)
  printf "%s // avg=%s\n" "$line" "$average"
done
```

Of course, the only `bc`-specific part of this is the format for the notation and the `bc` itself in the third last line. The same basic thing using `dc` might look like like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line; do
  set - ${line}
  c=$#
  string="0"
  for n in $*; do
    string+=" $1 + "
    shift
  done
  average=$(dc -e "4k $string $c / p")
  printf "%s // %s\n" "$line" "$average"
done
```

Note that my shell supports appending to strings with `+=`. If yours does not, you can adjust this as you see fit.

In both of these examples, we're printing our output to four decimal places -- with `scale=4` in bc, or `4k` in dc.  We are processing standard input, so if you named these scripts "calc", you might run them with command lines like:

```
$ ./calc < inputfile.txt
```

The `set` command at the beginning of the loop turns the `$line` variable into positional parameters, like `$1`, `$2`, etc. We then process each positional parameter in the `for` loop, appending everything to a string which will later get fed to the calculator.

---

**Also, you can fake it.**

That is, while bash doesn't support floating point numbers, it DOES support multiplication and string manipulation.  The following uses NO external tools, yet *appears* to present decimal averages of your input.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i total

while read line; do

  set - ${line}
  c=$#
  total=0
  for n in $*; do
    total+="$1"
    shift
  done

  # Move the decimal point over prior to our division...
  average=$(($total * 1000 / $c))
  # Re-insert the decimal point via string manipulation
  average="${average:0:$((${#average} - 3))}.${average:$((${#average} - 3))}"
  printf "%s // %0.3f\n" "$line" "$average"

done
```

The important bits here are:
* `declare` which tells bash to *add* to `$total` with `+=` rather than appending it as if it were a string,
* the two `average=` assignments, the first of which multiplies `$total` by 1000, and the second of which splits the result at the thousands column, and
* `printf` whose format enforces three decimal places of precision in its output.

Of course, input still needs to be integers.

YMMV.  I'm not saying this is how you *should* solve this, just that it's an option. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old post, but came up at the top my Google search, so thought I'd share what I came up with:

```
while read line; do
    # Convert each line to an array
    ARR=( $line )

    # Append each value in the array with a '+' and calculate the sum
    #   (this causes the last value to have a trailing '+', so it is added to '0')
    ARR_SUM=$( echo "${ARR[@]/%/+} 0" | bc -l)

    # Divide the sum by the total number of elements in the array
    echo "$(( ${ARR_SUM} / ${#ARR[@]} ))"
done < "$filename"
```