# Summing row in bash

Tags: bash

I'm a new user that is trying to learn bash, so I'm sorry if my code really bad or "stupid" because I learn bash from free pdf only.
My question is: I have a file called "number" that's simply contains

1     3     4     2     9

I want to read it and sum them all together, however my code doesn't work.
What I have so far is:

```
line=$(head -n 1 number)
echo "line"
while read $line
do
  sum=`expr $sum + $line`
  echo sum
done
```

Can someone help me to show the correct code? Also, when I call $line is it "1 3 4 2 9" or they split already become "1" "3" "4" "2" "9"?

Thank you.

Comment: What must be another student in your class asked about this just a few hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917920/bash-find-average-of-numbers-in-line/

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry about that. I didn't know he/she asked a similar questions. Thank you for your help.